# How can I use Macros in Delphi?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe6

How can I use Macros in Delphi? This feature is available in `FPC` for quite some time now. Could it be done with pre or post build events?

Example:

```
{$define sum:=a:=a+b;}
```

Comment: Macros in FPC are meant for a few simple cases (like simple {$ifdef mswindows} stdcall{$else}cdecl{$endif} macros. They are not meant for general programming, that's why they are not parametrizable. Generics and Inline indeed are proper solutions for cases where plain C uses macros.

Comment: You are thinking of conditional symbols. `{$DEFINE}` is more flexible in FreePascal than in Delphi.  FreePascal supports defining entire expressions that can be substituted into code at compile time, similar to C preprocessor macros. Read [Section 2.2](http://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/prog/progse5.html#x138-1390002.2) of the FreePascal documentation.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I am thinking of `{$Macro ON}` in `FPC`

Comment: When `{$MACRO ON}` is used, `{$DEFINE}` can define expressions, not just symbol names. Such extended macros are NOT "meant for simple cases" and ARE "meant for general programming". That is what I disagree about your earlier comment.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Yes I wish this was in Delphi. Pretty usefull.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot use macros in Delphi. No such functionality exists. The closest built in functionality would be an `inline` function.

---

You could certainly write your own pre-processor that expands macros. However, you won't be able to make that integrate well with the IDE. At least, not in a way that I would consider acceptable.

The problem is where to expand the macro to. You can hardly expand it to the original file, because you cannot realistically modify that. So you'd need to expand to a temporary file. And the compiler doesn't have any mechanism to build from a temporary files. I suppose you might expand to an include file. That may be the best option but it's going to be horrible to work with. For instance, consider the fun when debugging.

Comment: You can use an external pre-processor. You seem to missed that one.

Comment: Clearly you can write whatever external tools you like to generate code, but that's not really "using macros in Delphi" as per the question.

Comment: I agree `inline` looks pretty like macro in cpp world

Comment: @stanleyxu2005 you cannot inline always. There is quite a list in the documentation.

Comment: @stanleyxu2005 It's not really very similar. Macros are simple text substitution and incredibly free and powerful. With that power comes scope for epic scales of abuse! It all hinges on a pre-processor as part of the compilation chain which is simply not present in Delphi.

Comment: @user3764855 Since Delphi has no macros, and since writing your own pre-processor is probably inconvenient, maybe you could tell us what motivates the question and we can see if we can give advice on the best possible Delphi solution.

Comment: @user3764855 It won't be nice to use. Think about how this will work with the debugger. Which source file will be used. I guess you've already decided that macros are the only possible solution to your problem and don't want to tell us what the problem is.

Answer (score 1):

Delphi does not provide built-in functionality for macros. Maybe [DWScript](https://bitbucket.org/egrange/dwscript/) is what you are looking for.

Comment: Well, if we are prepared to use other tools then FPC as mentioned in the question sounds like a candidate .......

Answer (score -4):

This is limited macro functionality.

It's an example of routines who's code is implemented just once and then re-used to implement different parameter types.

```
It can be done as follows:
```

uDynArrays.pas example:

```
unit uDynArrays;

interface

type
  TDynIntArray = array of Integer;
  TDynSingleArray = array of Single;
  TDynDoubleArray = array of Double;

{ TDynIntArray }
function AsDynArray(const AValues: array of Integer): TDynIntArray; overload;
function IsIn(AValue: Integer; const AValues: array of Integer): Boolean; overload;
function GetIndex(AValue: Integer; const AValues: array of Integer): Integer; overload;
function FindMinMaxValue(const AnArray: array of Integer; out AMin, AMax: Integer): Boolean; overload;
function FindMinValue(const AnArray: array of Integer; out AMin: Integer): Boolean; overload;
function FindMaxValue(const AnArray: array of Integer; out AMax: Integer): Boolean; overload;

{ TDynSingleArray }
function AsDynArray(const AValues: array of Single): TDynSingleArray; overload;
function IsIn(AValue: Single; const AValues: array of Single): Boolean; overload;
function GetIndex(AValue: Single; const AValues: array of Single): Integer; overload;
function FindMinMaxValue(const AnArray: array of Single; out AMin, AMax: Single): Boolean; overload;
function FindMinValue(const AnArray: array of Single; out AMin: Single): Boolean; overload;
function FindMaxValue(const AnArray: array of Single; out AMax: Single): Boolean; overload;

{ TDynDoubleArray }
function AsDynArray(const AValues: array of Double): TDynDoubleArray; overload;
function IsIn(AValue: Double; const AValues: array of Double): Boolean; overload;
function GetIndex(AValue: Double; const AValues: array of Double): Double; overload;
function FindMinMaxValue(const AnArray: array of Double; out AMin, AMax: Double): Boolean; overload;
function FindMinValue(const AnArray: array of Double; out AMin: Double): Boolean; overload;
function FindMaxValue(const AnArray: array of Double; out AMax: Double): Boolean; overload;

implementation

function AsDynArray(const AValues: array of Integer): TDynIntArray;
begin
  SetLength(Result, Length(AValues));
  if Length(AValues) > 0 then
    system.Move(AValues[Low(AValues)], Result[0], Length(AValues) * SizeOf(Integer));
end;

function AsDynArray(const AValues: array of Single): TDynSingleArray;
begin
  SetLength(Result, Length(AValues));
  if Length(AValues) > 0 then
    system.Move(AValues[Low(AValues)], Result[0], Length(AValues) * SizeOf(Single));
end;

function AsDynArray(const AValues: array of Double): TDynDoubleArray;
begin
  SetLength(Result, Length(AValues));
  if Length(AValues) > 0 then
    system.Move(AValues[Low(AValues)], Result[0], Length(AValues) * SizeOf(Double));
end;

{$DEFINE IsIn}
function IsIn(AValue: Integer; const AValues: array of Integer): Boolean; {$I uDynArrays.inc}
function IsIn(AValue: Single; const AValues: array of Single): Boolean; {$I uDynArrays.inc}
function IsIn(AValue: Double; const AValues: array of Double): Boolean; {$I uDynArrays.inc}
{$UNDEF IsIn}

{$DEFINE GetIndex}
function GetIndex(AValue: Integer; const AValues: array of Integer): Integer; {$I uDynArrays.inc}
function GetIndex(AValue: Single; const AValues: array of Single): Integer; {$I uDynArrays.inc}
function GetIndex(AValue: Double; const AValues: array of Double): Double; {$I uDynArrays.inc}
{$UNDEF GetIndex}

{$DEFINE FindMinMaxValue}
function FindMinMaxValue(const AnArray: array of Integer; out AMin, AMax: Integer): Boolean; {$I uDynArrays.inc}
function FindMinMaxValue(const AnArray: array of Single; out AMin, AMax: Single): Boolean; {$I uDynArrays.inc}
function FindMinMaxValue(const AnArray: array of Double; out AMin, AMax: Double): Boolean; {$I uDynArrays.inc}
{$UNDEF FindMinMaxValue}

{$DEFINE FindMinValue}
function FindMinValue(const AnArray: array of Integer; out AMin: Integer): Boolean; {$I uDynArrays.inc}
function FindMinValue(const AnArray: array of Single; out AMin: Single): Boolean; {$I uDynArrays.inc}
function FindMinValue(const AnArray: array of Double; out AMin: Double): Boolean; {$I uDynArrays.inc}
{$UNDEF FindMinValue}

{$DEFINE FindMaxValue}
function FindMaxValue(const AnArray: array of Integer; out AMax: Integer): Boolean; {$I uDynArrays.inc}
function FindMaxValue(const AnArray: array of Single; out AMax: Single): Boolean; {$I uDynArrays.inc}
function FindMaxValue(const AnArray: array of Double; out AMax: Double): Boolean; {$I uDynArrays.inc}
{$UNDEF FindMaxValue}

end.
```

uDynArrays.inc example:

```
{$IFDEF IsIn}
var
  I: Integer;
begin
  Result := False;
  for I := Low(AValues) to High(AValues) do
    if AValue = AValues[I] then
      Exit(True);
end;
{$ENDIF}

{$IFDEF GetIndex}
var
  I: Integer;
begin
  Result := -1;
  for I := Low(AValues) to High(AValues) do
    if AValue = AValues[I] then
      Exit(I);
end;
{$ENDIF}

{$IFDEF FindMinMaxValue}
var
  I: Integer;
begin
  AMax := 0;
  AMin := 0;
  Result := Length(AnArray) > 0;
  if not Result then
    Exit;

  AMax := AnArray[Low(AnArray)];
  AMin := AMax;
  for I := Low(AnArray) to High(AnArray) do
    if AMax < AnArray[I] then
      AMax := AnArray[I]
    else if AMin > AnArray[I] then
      AMin := AnArray[I];
end;
{$ENDIF}

{$IFDEF FindMinValue}
var
  I: Integer;
begin
  AMin := 0;
  Result := Length(AnArray) > 0;
  if not Result then
    Exit;

  AMin := AnArray[Low(AnArray)];
  for I := Low(AnArray) to High(AnArray) do
    if AMin > AnArray[I] then
      AMin := AnArray[I];
end;
{$ENDIF}

{$IFDEF FindMaxValue}
var
  I: Integer;
begin
  AMax := 0;
  Result := Length(AnArray) > 0;
  if not Result then
    Exit;

  AMax := AnArray[Low(AnArray)];
  for I := Low(AnArray) to High(AnArray) do
    if AMax < AnArray[I] then
      AMax := AnArray[I];
end;
{$ENDIF}
```

Comment: This has absolutely nothing to do with the question asked. Did you read it? It asks about using compiler macros, which Delphi does not support. It has nothing to do with generics or dynamic arrays.

Comment: I've flagged your comment for a moderator. Name calling and personal attacks violate the Code of Conduct. And your answer is still wrong, because it does not answer the question asked, which is about compiler macros. Perhaps you should read it again. The code you posted has nothing to do with compiler macros, as in `{$define}`, that tell the compiler to do something. The poster is asking about using a macro in a specific way like the C preprocessor, which Delphi does not support, and your code does not change the fact that Delphi does not support it.